# I got runtime Error in making model with CNN

Tags: python, pytorch, classification

I want to make A model with Cnn.but it always show me Error on Tensor Size.I canot find in any part of my code this kind of sizes! it's ok with two classes params and it accured when I change it to 4
here is my code

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import os
import copy

import os
import shutil
import re

two_train =  "/Data/train/2"
two_val =  "/Data/val/2"
nine_train =  "/Data/train/9"
nine_val = "/Data/val/9"
seven_train =  "/Data/train/7"
seven_val = "/Data/val/7"
eight_train =  "/Data/train/8"
eight_val = "/Data/val/8"

two_files = os.listdir(two_train)
nine_files = os.listdir(nine_train)
seven_files = os.listdir(seven_train)
eight_files = os.listdir(eight_train)

# Make transforms and use data loaders

# We'll use these a lot, so make them variables
mean_nums = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std_nums = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

chosen_transforms = {'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean_nums, std_nums)
]), 'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean_nums, std_nums)
]),
}

# Set the directory for the data
data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/'

# Use the image folder function to create datasets
chosen_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
  chosen_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}

# Make iterables with the dataloaders
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(chosen_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
  shuffle=True, num_workers=8)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}

dataset_sizes = {x: len(chosen_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = chosen_datasets['train'].classes

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

dataset_sizes
# class_names
# device
mean_nums

def imshow(inp, title=None):
    inp = inp.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
    mean = np.array([mean_nums])
    std = np.array([std_nums])
    inp = std * inp + mean
    inp = np.clip(inp, 0, 1)
    plt.imshow(inp)
    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.pause(0.001)  # Pause a bit so that plots are updated


# Grab some of the training data to visualize
inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders['train']))
```

and I got This Error :

```
Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 198, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 83, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 83, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 55, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 65, 36] at entry 0 and [3, 61, 39] at entry
```

Error occured in last line and show me this error on console!
I seearch on the Web but I got nothing

Answer (score 0):

The error means that PyTorch is trying to stack 2 tensors, along the batch dimension, with different shapes.
This is due to the images in your dataset having different sizes.

One way to solve the problem is to add a [Resize](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize) transform, e.g.:

```
chosen_transforms = {'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((65, 40)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean_nums, std_nums)
]), 'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((65, 40)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean_nums, std_nums)
]),
}
```

You might also have to force the image loading with PIL:

```
# Use the image folder function to create datasets
chosen_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
  chosen_transforms[x], loader=torchvision.datasets.folder.pil_loader)
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
```

Comment: i add it and now it says it needs to be PIL but when I add PIL it says need to be Tensor or ndarray!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you try once again?